# How to use the current time in app to made an action (delete data from the data base) according to current time

Tags: java, android

I want to delete information from the app at six in the morning every day.
I could not do this in Android Studio and I would be happy if someone could help me.

my code below-

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
       @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat format = new 
          SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        String time = format.format(calendar.getTime());
       if (time.equals("06:00")) {
           mydb.deleteAllNames();
            mydb.deleteAllTasks();
        }
```

Comment: Please elaborate on 'I could not do this'. Is there an error? If so please provide it.

Comment: there is not an error.

Comment: What is not working

Comment: but, nothing is happening rhe data not deleted

Comment: Is the app definitely running at the time? A good way to test would be to display a message or print to console to check the code block is being run.

Comment: my goal is that he app will not open and still every day at six the data will be deleted

Comment: can you see if it runs at the moment

Comment: ok, it is working only if i run the app at the time i wrote

Comment: but as i said before i want the information to be deleted even if i dont run the app at rhe same moment i write un the code

Comment: You understand what I mean?

Comment: I guess something like [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and a [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to know if the device reboots (ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) would work. (You'd set up the AlarmManager again after a reboot.)

Comment: so you need to run without the application being open, edit your question as such